# Add attachment to message in Slack API

Tags: delphi, slack-api, delphi-xe

How can I add a large text file (actually a HTML file) as an attachment to a channel in Slack? A working example would be great. I use [SDriver](https://github.com/andrea-magni/SDriver) - the included demo works fine to send some strings, but I don't find anything on how to use attachments.

[What I did so far](https://gist.github.com/bero/e675bdf38c6e884be7e08377d6d52009):

```delphi
procedure TForm1.SendActionExecute(Sender: TObject);
var
  LWebHook: IMessageBuffer;
  LMessage: IMessage;
  LStopWatch: TStopWatch;
  vAttachment: IAttachment;
  vField: IFields;
begin
  LStopWatch := TStopWatch.StartNew;

  LMessage := TMessage.Create(EditMessage.Text + ' [' + TimeToStr(Now) + ']');
  LMessage.UserName := EditUserName.Text;
  LMessage.Icon_URL := EditIcon_URL.Text;
  LMessage.Icon_Emoji := EditIcon_Emoji.Text;
  LMessage.Channel := EditChannel.Text;

  vAttachment := LMessage.AddAttachment;
  vField := vAttachment.AddFields;
  vField.Title := 'Title';
  vField.Value := 'Value';

  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // How can I add a large text file as attachment here ?
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        
  LWebHook := TIncomingWebHook.Create(EditWebHookURL.Text, False);
  LWebHook.Push(LMessage);
  LWebHook.Flush;
end;
```

Comment: When the linked code is not available anymore nobody will be able to reproduce your problem - that's why code should go into the Q, not links.

Comment: Code was added now

Comment: Either your impression of "attachment" differs from [Slack's definition](https://api.slack.com/messaging/composing/layouts#attachments), or you miss that `IFields.Value` is meant to carry the content of your "_large text-file_" directly - so just open and read it.